# Uso de ser/estar cuando alguien es liberado

Tags: verbos, expresiones, cópulas

Hoy jugando con mi hijo mayor estábamos haciendo como que rescatábamos a un grupo de coches prisioneros de un malvado camión de basura. A la hora de poner a los coches en libertad, me salió decir:

> ¡Estamos libres!

Pero luego me quedé pensando en que la expresión común en estas situaciones es decir:

> ¡Somos libres!

Y claro, luego ya me quedé extrañado, dado que aunque esta segunda expresión es la que mejor me suena (al menos en la literatura), lo suyo sería usar la primera dado que se acaba de producir un cambio en la situación de los prisioneros (cambio de condición de prisionero a en libertad).

¿A qué se debe que se puedan usar los dos verbos en este caso? ¿Cuál de los dos sería el más adecuado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como en general con *ser/estar*, se trata de ver si es una condición permanente-inherente o transitoria-circunstancial. Una regla simple en este caso para determinar qué verbo usar es ver cuál se usa en el significado contrapuesto. Si vemos la definición del DRAE para *libre* encontramos:

> 2. adj. Que no **es** esclavo.
> 3. adj. Que no **está** preso.

Entonces

- En contraposición a *ser esclavo*, diremos *ser libre*
- En contraposición a *estar preso*, diremos *estar libre*

Notar que no podemos decir *está esclavo*❌, ni *es preso*❌.

Por lo tanto, lo que te salió decir en primer término es correcto, si dejas de estar priso, *estás libre*

Comment: Interesante la definición de libre: en una acepción usa el verbo "ser" y en la otra "estar". Se podría considerar que, dada la situación de alguien recién puesto en libertad, podría decir "estoy libre" para indicar su cambio de situación de preso a libre, o también "soy libre" para reivindicar su condición de ser libre (no esclavo), como expresando que es un ser libre que nunca debería haber sido encarcelado.

Answer (score 3):

"ser libre" es, en efecto, más común que "estar libre". Google books arroja estos resultados que, aunque no son determinantes para llegar a una conclusión categórica, ya nos dan algún indicio de frecuencia de uso (es sólo una búsqueda preliminar, ya que para una búsqueda más exhaustiva deberíamos intentar con otras formas de "ser" y "estar" y con el plural "libres"):

"estar libre"
About 43,400 results (0.63 seconds)

"ser libre"
About 237,000 results (0.23 seconds)

"estar libre" parecería requerir un complemento de régimen: "¡Estamos libres del malvado camión de basura!"

"ser libre" parecería ser una expresión más independiente.

Para marcar el cambio de estado, de la esclavitud a la libertad, y dejar en claro la acción de haber sido liberado, podríamos decir:

¡Ya somos libres!

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la expresión "ser libre" se puede tomar desde el punto de vista filosófico, por aquello de que el ser humano es un ser libre (tiene libre albedrío). Habría que ver qué resultados da la búsqueda si nos ceñimos al escenario de alguien recién puesto en libertad, lo cual puede ser complicado.

Answer (score 1):

**"Ser libre" se refiere casi exclusivamente a la condición de libertad de la persona.**

Por ejemplo, en el caso que has mencionado: los coches estaban presos, luego no eran libres; tras ser liberados, tu intuición es correcta y corresponde la frase:

> ¡Somos libres!

También lo puedes usar para hablar por ejemplo de la libertad de pensamiento o de movimiento:

> Soy libre de pensar lo que me dé la gana.
>   Soy libre para ir a donde quiera.

**"Estar libre" se usa normalmente como sinónimo de "estar disponible".**

Por ejemplo, si tu hijo mayor te pregunta si podéis volver a jugar mañana, y no tienes nada que hacer, puedes responderle:

> Sí, mañana estoy libre, puedo jugar contigo.

De igual manera, si no tienes pareja y alguien te pregunta si mantienes alguna relación, podrías responder:

> No, no tengo pareja, ahora mismo estoy libre

(aunque quedaría un poco frío).

**También se puede usar "estar libre de algo" para indicar un cierto tipo de inocencia**, sobre todo en expresiones de origen religioso, como en la famosa frase:

> ¡Quien esté libre de pecado, que tire la primera piedra!

Otros usos similares a este serían: estar libre de culpa, estar libre de sospecha, etc.